# Invalid issuer or signature error in autohosted app - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer

I'm creating my first app for SharePoint 2013. I follow [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179886%28v=office.15%29.aspx), that explains how to create autohosted app.

This piece of code I took from the article and didn't change anything in it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TokenHelper.TrustAllCertificates();
    string contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Request);

    if (contextTokenString != null)
    {
        // Get context token
        contextToken = TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);

        // Get access token
        sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(contextToken, sharepointUrl.Authority).AccessToken;

        // Pass the access token to the button event handler.
        Button1.CommandArgument = accessToken;
    }
}
```

However, when I run my deployed app, I get `SecurityTokenException: Invalid issuer or signature.`

Any advice how to solve this error would be appreciated.

```
 [SecurityTokenException: Invalid issuer or signature.]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.VerifySignature(String signingInput, String signature, String algorithm, SecurityToken signingToken) +873
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ReadTokenCore(String token, Boolean isActorToken) +498
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(String token) +7
   SharePoint_AutohostedApp1Web.TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(String contextTokenString, String appHostName) in c:\Users\tsch\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SharePoint-AutohostedApp1\SharePoint-AutohostedApp1Web\TokenHelper.cs:75
   SharePoint_AutohostedApp1Web.Pages.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\tsch\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SharePoint-AutohostedApp1\SharePoint-AutohostedApp1Web\Pages\Default.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: Tschareck, could you post what you did to solve this issue. I'm running into same issue deploying the same demo app and haven't found a fix yet. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have already found a way around this issue, but I resolved it by editing the permissions my App needed to the Host Web.  Originally I was just leaving it blank, but setting those permissions explicitly in the manifest got it working.

Comment: this did it for me. I constantly am forgetting to request access to the web. Weird for me is that I was able to connect without the permission, then it magically stopped working.

Comment: My comment doesn't stand entirely. This seems to be a caching issue perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it in my case.

Uninstall the app, then in the Office 365 Admin Center, click **apps** then **App Permissions**. Delete any app permissions left behind for your app, and install the app again.

I think what was happening was that it was using the wrong set of permissions and sending the app an invalid token.